# editing a model in more than one view

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My target is, to modify a model in more than one view.
Since sometimes my models have many properties I want to modify them in more than one view. Something like:

first page edits 2 properties, second page edits 3 other properties,...

the model looks like this:

```
public class LoadViewModel
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; } = -1;
    public PageViewModel PageViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class PageViewModel
{
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
    public int Param3 { get; set; }
}
```

my view on the Index-page looks like this:

```
@model LoadViewModel
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Load", "Home", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "page"}, new {lvm = Model}))
{
    <div id="page"></div>
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

and this is my action:

```
public ActionResult Load(LoadViewModel lvm = null)
{
    if (lvm == null) lvm = new LoadViewModel();
    lvm.CurrentPage += 1;
    TempData["CurrentPage"] = TempData["CurrentPage"] == null ? 0 : (int)TempData["CurrentPage"] + 1;
    if (!partialViewDict.ContainsKey((int) TempData["CurrentPage"]))
        TempData["CurrentPage"] = 0;
    return PartialView(partialViewDict[(int)TempData["CurrentPage"]], lvm);
}
```

the pages are just partials that are mapped:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> partialViewDict = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {0, "Pages/_Page1"},
    {1, "Pages/_Page2"},
    {2, "Pages/_Page3"},
};
```

and designed like this:

```
@using WebApplication1.Controllers
@model LoadViewModel
@{
    TempData["CurrentPage"] = 0;
}

@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PageViewModel.Param1)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PageViewModel.Param1)
```

this is working. When switching to Page2 the model is correctly set, but when hitting the `submit` the value of `Param1` (that I set in Page1) is resetted to `null` and only the values I set in the current partial are correct.

This is Page2:

```
@using WebApplication1.Controllers
@model LoadViewModel
@{
    TempData["CurrentPage"] = 1;
}
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PageViewModel.Param2)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PageViewModel.Param2)
```

When I add a `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PageViewModel.Param1)` into the partial, the value is still set. But I don't want the values to be resetted. I don't want to add an `@Html.HiddenFor` for all properties a set in a previous view. How can I prevent that the values are resetted when hitting `submit` without adding `@Html.HiddenFor` for all not listed attributes? Or is there any other possibility to catch my target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two pieces to this. First, the post itself, and getting that to validate. For that, each step should have its own view model, containing only the properties it's supposed to modify. This allows you to add all the validation you need without causing other steps to fail. In the end, you'll combine the data from all of these into your entity class or whatever.

Which brings us to the second piece. You need some way of persisting the data from each step. The only data that will exist after a POST is the data that was posted and anything in the session (which includes `TempData`). You could always create a bunch of hidden fields to store the data from the previous steps, but that can get a little arduous. Most likely, you'll just want to use the session.

`TempData` is basically a specialized instance of `Session`, so which you use doesn't really matter. With `TempData`, you'll need to remember call `TempData.Keep()` for each of the keys you've set for each step or you'll lose the previous steps on the next request. `Session` will keep them around for the life of the session, but you should remember to remove the keys at the end with `Session.Remove()`.

Comment: hmm.. so maybe creating a viewmodel for each step and then later map them to one if the last step is submitted? (I only can save them to database if the last step was submitted) - If there are 2 people running this, they won't override the TempData-Object from the other user?

Comment: Not at all. `Session`/`TempData` is specific to the client. A cookie is set on the client that uniquely identifies their session data.

Comment: mhh okay, and you have an idea if this could be a performance issue to store a big viewmodel in such a TempData? (maybe 50 properties with large strings). So I could, when submitting, map the viewmodel of the page to the big viewmodel (e.g. AutoMapper), that can be stored to the database when the user finished everything. Would this be a good procedure?

Comment: Performance should not be an issue. However, depending on your session store, there might be things to consider. In proc uses memory, so obviously, the more you do of this, the more RAM your server will need. That's not to say you need to go all out on RAM. It's just something you need to monitor. If you're using SQL Server or SessionState Server, you'll need to ensure that whatever you're putting in there is a primitive type or able to be serialized into an XML/JSON string.

Comment: Okay. :) Thank you for sharing your knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use @using (Html.BeginForm()) in your .cshtml?

Unfortunately this is MVC. MVC is stateless, which means if you don't render it then you loose it :(

If you use model binding and scaffolding, then you can save some time and work but at the end it will be the same solution.

Comment: but there has to be any solution to modify a model in more than one view!? else, it seems to be really static.. my target is to make an install-flow where the user can initialize and configure the application (windows-like after installing the OS) - and won't have to scroll the ironman (226 km).
No I'm already using `Ajax.BeginForm()`. with `Html.BeginForm()` it's not possible

Comment: Minor nit-picking, but just want to clarify: HTTP is stateless. MVC actually is not, as it supports the concept of sessions, which add state. However, assuming sessions are not used, then the requests will be "stateless".